# How can I prevent images from being stretched and grey space being added to my Elementor 3 card layout on my Wordpress site?

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I'm having difficulty with my Wordpress Site. I have a 3 card layout built with Elementor that looks great when it's shown in the preview however once the site is published all of the images get stretched and grey space is added to the bottom of the images.

I tried adjusting the parameters and resaving. I also compared the dimensions to my staging site, which is working fine, and the dimensions are completely the same but only the production site is having that issue.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.